# Chance to roll a $6$ at least $x$ times out of $y$ dice rolls

Tags: probability, dice, binomial-distribution

If I were to roll a die $y$-number of times, how do I calculate the probability of 
rolling a $6$ at least $x$-times?

Imagine that two people are making a bet over the outcome of a die roll. If the result is $1-5$, Tod pays Frank $100$ dollars. If the result is a $6$, Frank pays Tod $1000$ dollars. If this bet was repeated $60$ times, what is the probability that Tod will at least break even?

Comment: This is a straightforward application of a binomial distribution.  Given the probability of rolling a six on a specific die roll is $p$, letting $q=1-p$, and letting $X$ be the random variable counting the number of sixes rolled, you have $Pr(X\geq x)=\sum\limits_{k=x}^y Pr(X=k) = \sum\limits_{k=x}^y \binom{y}{k}p^kq^{y-k}$.  This can admittedly be tedious to calculate, and so for *large* numbers one often approximates the solution using the fact that a binomial distribution approaches a normal distribution.  These numbers are too small for that though to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Use binomial distribution $Prob.=\sum_{k=x}^y\binom{y}{k}p^k(1-p)^{y-k}$ where $p=\frac{1}{6}$

To get break even: number you need, $1000n -100(60-n) \ge 0$ or $n=6$.

Prob. of break even : use above formula for $y=60$ and $x=6$.

For calculation, get $1-Prob.=\sum _{k=0}^5$

Comment: @calculus $y=60$ is total number of rolls and $x=6$ is number of successes.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are defined in the question.